# mvc - how to avoid log out when refresh a page

Tags: ajax, wcf, session, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have built the MVC application with WCF service. The major problem I have experienced with refreshing page.

I have created a login page with session (`username and password`). But when you refresh the home page by pressing `F5`, it would automatically log out.

That is my problem. I need to stay the home page after refresh. I have been googling around to find a solution but it seems not helpful.

Any idea? Your advise or code example much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe cookies are not allowed in browser.

Comment: @X2 you think it would work if i create a new cookie and add it to cookie list?